# Cannot Create Files on iOS

Tags: app, file, document-template, apple-ios, create-document

I set up a Sharepoint Onlie site and it is planned to be used mainly on mobile devices. Working with existing files works great, but there is a huge problem, which I did not expect beforehand.

I cannot create any files in the sharepoint site on my iPhone.

I am using the same account on a PC and on the iPhone. But when I start the SharePoint App, navigate to the Library, there is no New button.

If I open the Sharepoint library in the safari browser, I see the New button, but it only lets me create folders, no files (see the screenshot).

I did not found anything related on the web and cannot believe, this ist how it works. What am I missing here?

We plan to use custom templates for creating files (like on the PC) and already created a bunch of them, we need this menu.

[image]